# Admob ad wants too much space

Tags: android, admob

I trying to put an admob add into my app but I think it is too big. In documentation minimum size is 320x50. Meanwhile in my app it wants 426 (which is odd as documentation does not mention such resolution) :

```
Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <426, 66>, Has: <324, 628>
```

Is there a way to force the smallest one? I tried ads:adSize="BANNER" and ads:adSize="SMART_BANNER" and both are too big.

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remember the `BANNER` size is 320x50dip, not pixels.  So, on higher density devices it takes more pixels.  The easiest way to make sure it has the right size is to size the `AdView` as `320x50dp` for banner size when you create it.